# Read S3 object from S3 bucket by signed url from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How to Read S3 object from S3 bucket by signed url from CloudFront.

1. I have S3 Bucket and have some files i.e. S3 Object.
2. S3 object are not public.
3. I create S3 Signed url by boto3 which available for 3600 seconds. It is working fine. After 3600 seconds singed url is invalid which is correct.

   `S3 Signed URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/BucketName/2018-11-01_19_43_31.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXX&Signature=XXXXXX&x-amz-security-token=xxxxxx&Expires=XXXXX`
4. I created CloudFront Distribution with Origin Settings to S3 bucket.

   `CloudFront endpoint: https://qwqwqwqwqw.cloudfront.net/`
5. I create signed url (step 3) and replace with end-point of CloudFront Distribution.

   `https://qwqwqwqwqw.cloudfront.net/2018-11-01_19_43_31.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXX&Signature=XXXXXX&x-amz-security-token=xxxxxx&Expires=XXXXX`

I able to download S3 object. **But after 3600 seconds also I able
    to download file. Test case is - do not download S3 object.**

Following is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity $SDSDSFDAs$"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What did you actually do in step 5? The procedure for creating CloudFront signed URLs is documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html

Comment: I am creating S3 pre-signed url and only adding cloudfront endpoint.  Updated question

Comment: That’s not, to the best of my knowledge, a viable procedure for creating a CloudFront signed URL. Please read the document I referenced earlier.